# How do i use a switch statement with a nested if statement with multiple OR values

Tags: php, session, permissions, switch-statement

I'm setting up a new website which will run as a CRM for the company I work for, when a member of staff comes to view a single customer I want that member of staff to only be allowed to view that single customer if they have permission. There are multiple ways a user can obtain permission, when they login a session is started with a security Level which is linked to a database. So lets say a user has Security Level 2 which is sales. They can view a customer BUT they can't view another sales persons lead, so I need to check if they were assigned that customer or if that customer has been shared with them or if they have been granted one time access to view that lead. I'm struggling with the best way to manage this, I thought I'd nailed it but it seems I've got it wrong.

Any chance someone can have a look below and let me know where/what I'm doing wrong

I have already tried a Switch statement with nested IF statements using OR as well, which I thought would work.

The code below is the switch statement, I fetch the share user id and access user id from 2 different databases and I've checked that they return the right results.

```
switch ($_SESSION['user_security']) {
    case '0': break;
    case '1': break;
    case '2': 
    if ($_SESSION['user_name'] != $assigned OR $_SESSION['user_id'] != $share['shareUserId'] OR $_SESSION['user_id'] != $access['userId']) {
        die("<center><h1>You Do Not Have Permission!</h1></center>");
    }
    break;
    default: 
    if ($_SESSION['user_id'] != $share['shareUserId'] OR $_SESSION['user_id'] != $access['userId']) {
        die("<center><h1>You Do Not Have Permission!</h1></center>"); break;    
    }
}
```

**Update**
So I've printed my variables to the screen, just so I can see how the system is working and this is where i'm getting really confused!

nameisAssigned = user_name == assigned
John Doe == John Doe

userIdMatchesShare = user_id == shareUserId
8 ==

userIdMatchesAccess = user_id == accessUserId
8 ==

So as you can see from above the first variable nameIsAssigned is true, but the other two can't find an ID for share or access meaning they don't exist. So this should equal true and allow the user through because one of the three conditions is true, but as I'm sure you guessed, it doesn't allow the user through...
Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Often it helps to break large expressions down into their components and thinking in positive ("when can the user access" not "when can they not"). Your code is equivalent to

```
$nameIsAssigned = $_SESSION['user_name'] == $assigned;
$userIdMatchesShare = $_SESSION['user_id'] == $share['shareUserId'];
$userIdMatchesAccess = $_SESSION['user_id'] == $access['userId'];

$canAccess = ($nameIsAssigned AND $userIdMatchesShare AND $userIdMatchesAccess);
if (!$canAccess) ....
```

It sounds like you wanted it to be

```
$canAccess = ($nameIsAssigned AND ($userIdMatchesShare OR $userIdMatchesAccess));
```

Comment: Ah ok sounds very close to what I mean. It's basically a massive OR statement, so it's $nameIsAssigned OR $userIdMatchesShare OR $userIdMatchesAccess. But my OR statements don't seem to work

Comment: "a or b or c" gives TRUE if at least one of a, b, or c gives TRUE. If your "OR statements don't seem to work" check each branch individually